# New user, can not use contrib

Tags: clojure

I am new to Clojure and can not use `clojure.contrib.math`.
All I really want to do is exponentiation `(power 2 3) --> 8`

I have been looking all morning for a solution but have only become more confused.

If i try `(use 'clojure.contrib.math)` i get a file not found error. Suspecting a classpath issue I tried to resolve it that way, only to not be able to locate a contrib jar...

Then I see that `contrib` is perhaps deprecated.

So the simple question, how do I access math functions?

clojure 1.5.1
Leiningen 2.2.0

Tahnks

Comment: Have you installed clojure.contrib.math and is it in a place where clojure can find it?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, clojure.contrib has been deprecated. The replacement for clojure.contrib.math is [clojure.math.numeric-tower](https://github.com/clojure/math.numeric-tower/). You will need to add it as a dependency in your project.clj file, as per the instructions in the README.

Here's an example for the particular function you mentioned:

```
(clojure.math.numeric-tower/expt 2 3) ;=> 8
```

See the [Where Did Clojure.Contrib Go](http://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Where+Did+Clojure.Contrib+Go) document for all the replacement libraries.

Answer (score 3):

You can also call through to Java static methods like this:

```
(Math/pow 2 3) ;=> 8.0
```